# Не работает событие OnEpilog в 1с битрикс

Tags: битрикс

в /bitrix/php_interface/init.php прописал

```
AddEventHandler("main", "OnEpilog", "renderSeoTags");
function renderSeoTags(){
        $APPLICATION->SetPageProperty('description',  '123');
}
```

но description на всех страницах остался прежним. Может есть какой то другой способ менять description (нужно будет в нем заменить плейсхолдеры)?

Comment: Переменная `$APPLICATION` определена глобально? Откуда в функции `renderSeoTags()` доступ к этой переменной? Пропишите `global $APPLICATION`

Comment: @Anatoly всёравно не работает, если прописать это в /bitrix/header.php то работает, но срабатывает почему то 2 раза и оба раза $APPLICATION->GetProperty('description') возвращает разные description

Comment: Так где у Вас определена переменная $APPLICATION?

Comment: @Anatoly добавил global $APPLICATION; в renderSeoTags

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось что есть ещё 1 init.php в /local/php_interface и он имеет больший приоритет чем тот что в /bitrix/php_interface. Прописал то же самое в нем (с global $APPLICATION) и всё заработало